# Upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 is not working

Tags: apt, upgrade

This command `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core` is not working to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 apache2.2-bin gdebi-core packagekit-backend-aptcc packagekit-tools python3-packagekit zlib1g-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/trusty/main i386 Packages
(/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ondrej_php_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

The previous command was

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: otherwise, do you have steps to do this?, i was using the following: https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04/

Comment: I would always stick to *official* or *authorized* documents rather than bloggers, for example - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenialUpgrades   Yes if you trust and know the skillset of the blogger they can be easier (being less committee driven as some *official* things can be), however the duplicate entry error you get you would have got before & ignored. You must correct it one of the duplicate entries & try again (any `sudo apt update` should throw that warning for example).  PPAs maker release-upgrading more difficult so are often safer to remove (purge) then return post-upgrade.